# What's a security clearance and why does it matter so much?

Tags: plot-explanation, oppenheimer

In the movie *Oppenheimer*, we repeatedly hear the term security clearance. I have never heard of that concept before. Even Google search doesn't satisfy me because I can't find why it's so important.

Comment: https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppenheimer_security_hearing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> A security clearance allows an individual filling a specific position to have access to classified national security information up to and including the level of clearance that they hold as long as the individual has a “need to know” the information and signed a non-disclosure agreement.

Source is the official [US Department of State](https://www.state.gov/security-clearances#:%7E:text=What%20work%20does%20a%20security%20clearance%20allow%20a%20person%20to%20%20do?)

It means that only people with the required level of clearance may work/see/discuss any problem involving national security. The higher you go in the organization, the more you're entitled to know. And very few knew about the bomb at that time.

If you lose your clearance, you lose your ability to work at/for government level/places that require such access.

More : [top secret clearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_clearance#Top_Secret) and [Q clearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_clearance).

Comment: And if you lose your clearance, it means that you no longer have access to government funding or the ability to hold certain positions.

Comment: It would definitely help this answer to add that point.  His clearance being revoked effectively removed his ability to work the field of nuclear weapons development, a field that he had developed from almost scratch over a decade before.  OP has been able to google the definition but wants to know why this is so important

Comment: That seemed so obvious that I didn't mentioned it. Clarified.

Comment: Not sure about the 1940s but today having a clearance unlocks access to many high-paying jobs and losing your clearance means you lose access to those jobs. Merely having a clearance makes you more valuable as an employee and having a top secret or higher clearance makes you almost indispensable. A TS job can easily pay 50% more than the same job in a non-cleared environment.

Comment: I don't know much about the US as I'm not American, but, as European, my father had, in the 60/70's, security clearance to work in nuclear power plants and they not only did very deep and tuned background checks but it also meant better jobs and more money.